# understanding how synchronized keyword works

Tags: java, synchronized

In the following code I was expecting only one of the two threads to enter the `halt()` function and then halt the program. But it seems as if both the threads are entering into the `synchronized` halt() function. Why could this be happening??

```
package practice;

class NewThread implements Runnable {
  String name; // name of thread
  Thread t;
  boolean suspendFlag;

  NewThread(String threadname) {
    name = threadname;
    t = new Thread(this, name);
    System.out.println("New thread: " + t);
    suspendFlag = false;
    t.start(); // Start the thread
  }

  // This is the entry point for thread.
  public void run() {
    try {
      for(int i = 15; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        halt();
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");
    }
    System.out.println(name + " exiting.");
  }

  synchronized void halt() throws InterruptedException
  {
      System.out.println(name + " entered synchronized halt");
      Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      r.halt(9);
      System.out.println(name + " exiting synchronized halt"); // This should never execute
  }
}

class Practice{
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    NewThread ob1 = new NewThread("One");
    NewThread ob2 = new NewThread("Two");

    // wait for threads to finish
    try {
      System.out.println("Waiting for threads to finish.");
      ob1.t.join();
      ob2.t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
    }

    System.out.println("Main thread exiting."); // This should never execute
  }
}
```

Comment: Aren't those two separate objects? If I understand your code correctly, e'ach thread executing on its own object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synchronization is done on each object. If you have 2 objects, 2 threads might get into the `halt()` method simultaneously. You can make the method static to achieve what you want. By making it static the lock will be put on the corresponding `Class` object (`NewThreadOne.class`) which is unique regarding of the number of instances of `NewThreadOne`.

Answer (score 7):

synchronized does not lock a method, it locks an object.

You have one method but two objects. Each thread locks its own object and calls halt().

Answer (score 1):

You have Used `2 objects` for `2 threads` as their `monitor lock`....

So your code is working fine, with **each thread accessing the lock of its own object to access the** `halt()` method....

In `synchonized keyword`, you **achieve the lock of an object**, by which the thread gets an access to the `synchronized methods or atomic statements` within that class......

Answer (score 1):

The `synchronized` method is using this for locking. In your case, you have 2 different objects, as you are building 2 thread instances, so you are not locking on the same object. In order to have the synchronization behavior you expected, you need to make the `halt` method `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Its not recommended to use String object as lock in java synchronized block because string is immutable object and literal string and interned string gets stored in String pool. so by any chance if any other part of code or any third party library used same String as there lock then they both will be locked on same object despite being completely unrelated which could result in unexpected behavior and bad performance. instead of String object its advised to use new Object() for Synchronization in Java on synchronized block.